# How to lock multiple records in db2 procedure?

Tags: sql, db2, procedure

I need to lock a couple of records by using 'Select * from table where ** for update with RS".

I tested and found that in DB2 procedure 'select from' must used together with 'into' and if the resultset is more than one you must use 'bulk collect' which needs the procedure to be written in PL/SQL which I'm not familiar.

Is there any way I can lock the records only by using select from?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Such locks get released the next commit or rollback.  Remember that autocommit may be enabled by default.  Your testing may be invalid.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem to me. Why do you think you need to lock a couple of records?